# Vue Router push works but goes back to the original component after a moment

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, axios

I am experiencing this problem with my Login component. The idea is that after the email and password are validated, the component changes to a secure page. But what happens is that after 1 or 2 seconds the application returns again to the Login component.

This is my first web application and maybe I don't know how to search for solutions correctly, but I have not found anything on the internet.

Here is the code for the Login component:

```html
<template>
    <div class="vue-template">
        <form>
            <h3>Bienvenido</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Correo electrónico</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="user.mail"/>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-lg" v-model="user.password"/>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg btn-block" v-on:click='auth_user()'>
                Iniciar sesión
            </button>

            <p class="forgot-password text-right mt-2 mb-4">
                <router-link to="/forgot-password">¿Olvidaste tu contraseña?</router-link>
            </p>

            <p> {{ response }} </p>

        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    export default {
        name: 'Login',
        data() {
            return {
                user: {
                    mail: "",
                    password: "",
                },
                response: ""
            }
        },

        methods: {
            async auth_user(){
                if(this.user.mail != "" && this.user.password != ""){
                    axios({ method: "POST", 
                            "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/auth/", 
                            "data": this.user, 
                            "headers": { "content-type": "application/json"}
                            }).then(   
                                (result) => {                                    
                                    if (result.data == true) {
                                        this.response = "¡Hola de nuevo!";
                                        this.$router.replace('/secure');
                                    } else {
                                        this.response = "Correo o contraseña incorrecta"
                                    }                               
                                }, 
                                (error) => { 
                                    console.error(error) 
                                }                
                            )
                } else {
                    this.response = "Debe ingresar un correo y una contraseña."
                }


            }

        }
    }
</script>
```

Please tell me if you need another part of the code.
Note: this problems happens with every component and not just the 'Secure' one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicking the button will submit the form which will reload the page. You want to prevent the form from being submitted.

```html
<form @submit.prevent>
```

Comment: Thank you very much : )